# Implement AndroidQuery for getting last version of my app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-query, aquery

I would like to check by code if the app installed on device is the last update. I've tried many things but does not work. Finally I've found this interensting API: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/Service. I'm trying to implement it but i find it kinda difficult for me (I'm quite new in this world). I would like to know if anybody can help me to do this. I don't care if I have to use another API or maybe I can use a google's API to get this information. I just wanto get the version number like: "Application.getLastUpdate" (this is just an example) and compare to app installed version. Can anybody give me a hint?? I would appreciate it too much. Sorry if I haven't explain well myself, I can try it again. Thanxs a lot.

Comment: You want to do it for all the apps installed on the device ?

Comment: No! just the app I'm programming

Comment: Do you have access to an online server ?

Comment: Let's see, you know you have the option to update automatically your apps but you can also say no to updates. So I want to make sure that people update my app when I want. Yes I have an online server and it would be easy to check last update using my database but that's my last option, I would like to do it using google play